# Return Array of Data using Google Assistant from Firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, actions-on-google

The structure I have for my firebase database is like this:
fruits:
     apple,5
     banana,6

I want to put apple and banana in an array so that when i give a command to Google Assistant, it would give me apple, 5 and banana, 6. The code I have is like the one below:

```
 function handleCommand(agent) {
    return admin.database().ref('Fruits').child().once("value").then((snapshot) =>{
        var i;
        var fruitlist=[];

        //puts each snapshot child of 'Fruit' in an array
        snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
            var itemVal = item.val();
            fruitlist.push(itemVal);
        });

        //outputs command in google assistant
        for (i=0; i < fruitlist.length; i++) {
            agent.add(fruitlist[i]);
        }   

    })
```

The default response is "not available".

I get the following in the execution logs:

> Firebase.child failed. Was called 0 aruguments. expects at least 1.

I do not know which argument to put inside the Firebase.child. if i want all fruits to be "spoken" by Google Assistant. Below is a picture of my firebase structure.

[image]

The error looks like the one below:
[image]

What I am currently doing now to just output the fruits are manually entering each child in the code like this and removed the ".child" in the return statement:
[image]

Which gives me the output below which is also what I want to see but using arrays as the solution I am using now is very much hardcoded:
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify what you mean by "does not work at all". What errors are you getting? Is it returning anything at all? How have you set things up to call `handleCommand()`?

Comment: @Prisoner Updated the contents of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, and as you surmise, the `child()` call expects a parameter - in particular, the name of the child node you want to get information from. However, since you want *all* the children of the "Fruits" node - you don't need to specify it at all. The `child()` call just navigates down through the hierarchy, but you don't need to navigate at all if you don't want to.

The snapshot you get back will have a value of the entire object. In some cases, this can be pretty large, so it isn't a good idea to get it all at once. In your case, it is fairly small, so not as big a deal.

On the JavaScript side, you can now handle that value as an object with attributes and values. Your original code didn't quite do what you said you want it to, however - you're getting the value, but ignoring the name (which is the attribute name or key). You can iterate over the attributes of an object in a number of ways, but I like getting the keys of the object, looping over this, getting the value associated with the key, and then "doing something" with it.

While I haven't tested the code, it might look something like this:

```
 function handleCommand(agent) {
    return admin.database().ref('Fruits').once("value").then((snapshot) =>{
        // Get an object with all the fruits and values
        var fruits = snapshot.val();

        // Get the keys for the attributes of this object as an array
        var keys = Object.keys( fruits );

        // Iterate over the keys, get the associated value, and do something with it
        for( var i=0; i<keys.length; i++ ){
          var key = keys[i];
          var val = fruits[key];
          agent.add( `The number of ${key} you have are: ${val}` );
        }

    })
```

While this is (or should be) working Firebase and JavaScript, there are a couple of problems with this on the Actions on Google side.

First, the message returned might have some grammar problems, so using your example, you may see a message such as "The number of Apple you have are: 1". There are ways to resolve this, but keep in mind my sample code is just a starter sample.

More significantly, however, the call to `agent.add()` with a string creates a "SimpleResponse". You're only allowed two simple responses per reply in an Action. So while this will work for your example, it will have problems if you have more fruit. You can solve this by concatenating the strings together so you're only calling `agent.add()` once.

Finally, you may wish to actually look at some of the other response options for different surfaces. So while you might read out this list on a speaker, you may read a shorter list on a device with a screen and show a table with the information. Details about these might be better addressed as a new StackOverflow question, however.

Comment: Thank you so much for this and for explaining in detail! I have been stuck on this problem for several days now.